# Pass a javascript variable value into input type hidden value inside a form

Tags: javascript, web, hidden-field

I am trying to send the user's country name as a hidden input field of a contact form in WP.

The geolocation service is http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp 
and to access this service, I have added the following Javascript call within the head of the page:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Once added, you will have geo-localized javascript functions available to your entire page, and the one I want to use is

```
function geoplugin_countryName()
```

The contact form is embedded in the body:

```
<form name='Form' id='' method='post' action='https://app.url.com/...'>

<div class='form-group'>
<input type='email' name='Email' class='form-control' placeholder='Email Address' value='' required >
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
<input type='hidden' name='Country' class='form-control' value='' id='detected-country'>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
<input class='button' type='submit' name='submit'; value='Submit'>
<input type='hidden' name='reflink' value=''>
</div>
</form>
```

I have tried adding the following code just after Country input line of the form. The form is sent as I get the user email, but the "country" field is sent empty.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var country=0;
function geoplugin_countryName()
{
return country;
document.getElementById('detected-country').value=country;
}
</script>
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you add the error that you have received.  saying that it doesn't work is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The form is sent, as I get the user's email, but the country field is empty. I have edited the question.

Comment: This line is never read document.getElementById('detected-country').value=country; because it is after a return.

Comment: Actually I have tried different ways. Do you have a suggestion how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('detected-country').value = geoplugin_countryName();
</script>
```

Below link has the example code.

https://www.geoplugin.com/examples

Comment: I didn't downvote. I have tried it but the country field is still sent empty. Thanks.